# How to remove ui-modules JS file from frontend?

Tags: javascript, magento2.4

I would like to remove js file on frontend side from the `[magento_root_direcotry]\lib\web\jquery\ui-modules\sortable.js` path

I tried to remove the JS file by the below code but no luck

I tried to remove the js code in the following path `/app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`

Here is the code which I put in `default_head_blocks.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
        <remove src="lib::jquery/ui-modules/sortable.js" />
    </head>
</page>
```

After the put above code, I ran `setup:upgrade` and pub static command and flush the cache but still loading that sortable js file in the network tab, I also checked in incognito mode.

Answer (score 0):

basically, you can't do that. Because this is requireJS dependency mechanism. You can't remove it when it is already required somewhere in the code. The only way that you can determine which file should be called instead call all of it. This means reducing less js file requests to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly remove the widgets which you don't use in your project in this file

> <magento_root>/lib/web/jquery/compact.js

Although you need to keep track of this file while deploying to production. I wish there was a better way to remove so many unused widgets and had a better way to add new/updated widgets.

Comment: and what about when I upgrade the magento newer version ?

Comment: In case you have not fixed this problem and want to upgrade to a new version of magento, this problem will still happen

Answer (score -2):

**for CMS:** cms_index_index.xml

**for Default:** default_head_blocks.xml

```
app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/Magento_Theme/layout
```

make use of the  tag under the  tag to remove the JavaScript file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <remove src="js/filename.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Comment: You put same code in your answer which I put in my question